# Show ppt in online without using thirdparty tool

Tags: php, jquery, html, slideshow, powerpoint

I need to show PPT file as slide show in my online server. I don't know how to show using **PHP or HTML or JQUERY** code .
Please help me if anyone know to do this.

Still when the PPT files clicked it's going to download. I need to slide show here.

Comment: I don't think you can read PPT files easily, much less translate them to HTML.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak How to translate them as HTML?

Comment: Assuming its served with appropriate headers,  you can just point at the ppt file (in an iframe if desired), and rely on the user's browser displaying the ppt. Or, e.g., use Google drive to make it a accessible to all browsers/users.

Comment: In theory, yes. PHP is turing-complete and has file I/O and the PPT format is well-defined (or, at the very least, has a reference implementation). In practice? Maaaybe there's a PHP library or a Javascript viewer.

Comment: Check the AD in the right-hand side panel, however. StackOverflow ADs are community-powered (at least some of them), so they should be (at least somewhat) relevant: http://www.aspose.com/.net/powerpoint-component.aspx?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=so%2Bslides%2Bside

Comment: PPT files > PowerPoint 2007 should be openxml, so readable relatively easy. Otherwise, you need to have access to a windows server, with Powerpoint installed, and use COM object

Comment: @DamienPirsy apart from reading, there's the other whole issue of converting the full range of features to HTML/Javascript.

Comment: @JanDvorak So What? Once you can read them  you can process and display however you want. The main issue is _reading_, then you decide how to present them. Anyway, PowerPoint has commands to export all slides as jpeg, but for that you _do need_ to interface to the PowerPoint program

Comment: AD7six:  browsers don't display PPT presentations.  They can host a PPT window in an iFrame only if the local system has PPT or the PPT viewer installed.  To answer the original question literally, it can't be done.  Some sort of third-party tool will be needed, whether it's one provided by an outside source or by the user.  One question to consider, @Sankar, is: Does any conversion have to take place on the server, or can you convert the PPT to HTML/Flash/PDF/Whatever on a local PC then upload it to the server?

Comment: @Steve Rindsberg still I did not have any convertor. I'm using google docs inside the iframe for showing PPT. But I need without using third party like google docs. Ok I will try to use uploading convertor

Comment: Good point about google docs (and apologies to ADsix about that as well).  I'm pretty sure you can host an instance of Microsoft's PPT web app in an iframe as well.  Not a solution to your problem but it might be for others.